Why does .NET Upgrade Assistant say "API does not exist" for pretty much all of NUnit when targeting .NET 8?
I'm using .NET Upgrade Assistant to analyze a bunch of .NET Framework 4.8 projects to assess their ability to Upgrade to .NET 8.
Most issues the Analyzer finds are from unit test projects, which basically list every NUnit type and method as "does not exist":

NUnit.Framework.Assert
NUnit.Framework.Is
NUnit.Framework.TestAttribute
etc...

I've upgraded NUnit to 4.1.0 and NUnit3TestAdapter to 4.6.0 which should be compatible with .NET 8
Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk is on Version 17.10.0
I've not found anything online that would indicate some kind of incompatibility. Can I just ignore these issues from the .NET Upgrade Assistant? It's a bit annoying because those issues make up 95% of the analysis results and really clutter up the output.
